# Tombstone scanning in system.log

Tags: cassandra, datastax, scylla, tombstone

I have a cassandra cluster with less delete use case. I found in my system.log "**Read 10 live and 5645464 tombstones cells in keyspace.table**" What does it mean? please help to understand.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more important thing to keep in mind when working with Cassandra is that tombstones cells do not directly correlate to deletes.

When you insert `null` value to an attribute when performing your insert, Cassandra internally marks that attribute/cell as a tombstone. So, even if you don't have a lot of deletes happening, you could end up with an enormous number of tombstones. Easy and simple solution is to not insert `null` values for an attribute while inserting.

As per this statement `Read 10 live and 5645464 tombstones cells in keyspace.table` goes, there might be a table scan for a query happening that is scanning `10` cells and `5645464` number of tombstones (cells with `null` value) while doing so is what I am guessing. Need to understand what type of queries are being executed to gain more insight into that.

Comment: what does it mean 10 live? and 5645464?

Comment: To make it sound simple, if you have a query like `select * from keyspace.table where id = 'abc' and cluster_key_with_int_value > 10 limit 10` then, cassandra will do a range scan on your table and log the above statement. Where 10 is the valid number of rows, and `5645464` is the number of tombstones encountered while gathering your 10 rows.

Answer (score 2):

For Cassandra, all the information recorded is immutable. This means that when you have a delete operation (explicit with a delete statement or with a Time To Live [`TTL`] clause), the database will add another record with a special flag named tombstone. All these records will stay on the database until the `gc_grace_seconds` periods have passed; the default is 10 days.

In your case, the engine found out that most of the records retrieved were deleted, but they are still waiting for the gc_grace_seconds to pass, to let compaction reclaim the space. One possible option to fix the issue is to decrease `gc_grace_seconds` for that table.

For more information, please refer to [this article](https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2016/07/27/about-deletes-and-tombstones.html) from the Last Pickle.

Comment: Yes, but What does it mean "10 live 5745464 tombstones"?

Comment: it means that from 5745474 records retrieved, 10 were useful, and 5745464 are marked to be deleted. This amount of tombstones will have a serious negative impact when doing reads.

Comment: 10 is not tombstone data? only 5745464

Comment: right, those 10 records are actually usable read data. The other 5.7 million of records were retrieved, but found flagged as deleted, so they can't be used; that flag is the tombstone